# How to calculate median over RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] in Spark efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, median

What I want to do like this:
http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com
Find the median value of each column.
It can be done by collecting the RDD to driver, for a big data which will become impossible.
I know Statistics.colStats() can calculate mean, variance... but median is not included.
Additionally, the vector is high-dimensional and sparse.

Comment: i collect the RDD to driver, then calculate it.

Comment: @guxiang That approach is troublesome, because some datasets won't fit in only one computer

Comment: @guxiang what vector? could you show us?

Comment: Your problem (and the reason colStats doesn't include median) is that median requires iterating through every value (the very last value can change the result). So it doesn't really fit with Spark or any parallel computation. Are you sure you really do need the median?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsantothe vector is like this:

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto the vector is Array[Double], high-dimensional up to 400.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul yes, I agree with you, I really want to replace the median with mean, but the median is more meaningful in my question.

Comment: How sparse are your columns? Is there a small upper bound to the number of non-empty entries in any one column?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I don't do some statistics, one column could be dense or sparse, but sparse is more common.

Comment: How do you represent sparse vector using `Array[Double]`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't understand the vector part, however this is my approach (I bet there are better ones):

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, -1, 12, 3, 0, 3))
val n = a.count() / 2

println(n) // outputs 3

val b = a.sortBy(x => x).zipWithIndex()
val median = b.filter(x => x._2 == n).collect()(0)._1  // this part doesn't look nice, I hope someone tells me how to improve it, maybe zero?

println(median) // outputs 2
b.collect().foreach(println) // (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (3,5) (12,6)
```

The trick is to sort your `dataset` using `sortBy`, then zip the entries with their index using `zipWithIndex` and then get the middle entry, note that I set an odd number of samples, for simplicity but the essence is there, besides you have to do this with every column of your dataset.

Comment: "The trick is to sort your dataset using sortBy," sloooow. There are faster algorithms, but they're still O(N). Also, in the OP's example he has  up to 400 entries per row which means sorting 400 times

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Well I said in my answer "I bet there are better ones", I hope someone posts them so I can learn :)

Comment: Some 2021 news here, no Spark or MLLIB **optimized median**?